# Recent posts by taxonomy and filter by tag

Tags: taxonomy, tags

I would like to display in the single page sidebar all the posts related with the Current Custom Taxonomy (taxonomy name: authors) and also filter the list of posts by a tag or category.

I found this on wordpress codex. With this code I can see a list of posts filter by Tag 'tag_slug'.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tag' => 'tag_slug',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'authors',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'elenap',
            )  
        ),
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                // no posts found   
            }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

How can I get the current taxonomy? Like:

```
'terms' => $currenttaxonomy,
```

Comment: Your taxonomy name is not people but authors and you have to put the term name in the terms field

Comment: Yes, I know ;) I just pasted the code from wordpress codex.
Now I edited the code above.

Comment: Please use the site search for *related posts*

Comment: Would you mind posting also the code you run the query?

Comment: @Laxmana, I edited the code with the loop after WP_Query.

Comment: I'm sorry @PieterGoosen.. you're right. 
I searched for "related posts" but I can't see something like my problem to call 'dynamically' the current term in my single page sidebar.. :( Can you give me some of the questions you answered about that? Thank you

Comment: You did not search.

Comment: [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188561/31545) is just one of the many **I** have done. All you need to do is add your tag filtering

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you very much. I'll let you know if it works for me. Or maybe I will ask for some help.. ;)

Comment: @PieterGoosen you are fantastic!:D I add my tag filter and it works perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it worked out. Enjoy :-)