# How to check if there are posts with the same tag

Tags: posts, loop, tags

I have this code but I can't get to delete the div with the class `otrasObras`

```
<?php
$test = "";
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $test .= ',' . $tag->name; 
    }
}
$test = substr($test, 1);
query_posts('tag='.$test.'&showposts=-1');
if(have_posts()){
?>
<div class="otrasObras">
    <h3>Contenido relacionado:</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if($post->ID != $idPost):
            ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  title="Ver la obra <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
        endif;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I read a bit about this in here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query but they were using the object syntax.

EDIT: `.otrasObras` is a module that I want to show only when it has content, and the content are other posts with the same tag, so if there are no more posts with that tag, I don't want it to pass the if(have_posts()) conditional, but this seems to not work, as it gets printed all the time

Comment: what are you trying to acheive. Nothing is clear from whatever you have explained so far

Comment: .otrasObras is a module that I want to show only when it has content, and the content are other posts with the same tag, so if there are no more posts with that tag, I don't want it to pass the `if(have_posts())` conditional, but this seems to not work, as it gets printed all the time

Comment: Check [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188561/31545). Use `post_tag` as taxonomy for build in tags :-)

Comment: Just one important note, **never ever** use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query object. Related posts relies on this main query object, so you don't just break the main query object, but you also break related posts functions. Use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` instead

Answer (score 1):

this code is with in the loop of single.php , RIGHT?
If so then give this code the try , it should work . Problem with your code seems that you are using `showpost`, rather you should be using `posts_per_page`

Plus i see this fragments of code like

```
`$test = ""; 

$test .= ',' . $tag->name; 

$test = substr($test, 1);`
```

I don't seem to find its use.

And then i see this `if($post->ID != $idPost)`

$idPost seems to be the id of the single post , whose tags you get initially , right?

Then this is how i will try to solve this problem.

```
  <?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) :
?>
    <div class="otrasObras">
      <h3>Contenido relacionado:</h3>
      <ul>
<?php    foreach($posttags as $tag) :        
        $my_args= array('tag_id'=>$tag->term_id,
                        'posts_per_page'=>2,   
                        );
        $myloop= new WP_Query($my_args); 

        if($myloop->have_posts()): 

            if($myloop->have_posts()):
?>

                    <?php
                    while ($myloop->have_posts()) : $myloop->the_post();                    
                    if(($myloop->post->ID) == $idPost)continue;
                    ?>

                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  title="Ver la obra <?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    break;                    
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_query();
                    ?>

<?php
            endif;
        endif;
    endforeach;
?>
     </ul>
            </div>    
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Check your code here http://phpcodechecker.com/ because it is broken

Comment: @Vandervals i missed  > in 'tag_id'=>$tag->term_id , anyways i updated the answer .

Comment: This has no errors but doesn't seem to work either as now the related posts never show....

Comment: @Vandervals Please see the updated answer

Comment: @Vandervals  plz let me know if it doesn't work, coz i spent a quite a bit time figuring this out

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It shows the panel all the time

Comment: panel.....? means

Comment: Oh, sorry! The panel is the first div.