# How can hide widget title if custom widget is empty

Tags: widgets

I created my Custom Widget with a category filter select. The widget show me the related posts of the current taxonomy term and filter by the selected category.

I would like to hide the widget title if the widget is empty (if there's no related posts).

How can I do?

Here's my code:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $limit = $instance['limit'];
        $cat = $instance['cat'];
        $show_thumbnail = isset( $instance['show_thumbnail'] ) ? $instance['show_thumbnail'] : false;

            echo $args[ 'before_widget' ];      


                if ( !empty( $title ) ) 
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; 

                $cat_select = array( 
                'numberposts' => $limit,
                'cat' => $cat,  
            ); ?>

               /******* function to get the posts of current taxonomy term *******/
                <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts_widget' ) ) { ?>

                    <?php $related_posts = get_related_posts_widget( 'authors', $cat_select );
                        if ( $related_posts ) { ?>


                            <ul class="related-cat">
                            <!-- Widget loop -->
```

Thank you in advance

---

EDIT

I use the code you suggested me [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188473/show-related-posts-on-single-page-by-custom-taxonomy-on-custom-post/188561#188561)

And I call the function get_related_posts_widget from functions.php. I adapted the query with the selected cat ($cat).

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $limit = $instance['limit'];
        $cat = $instance['cat'];
        $show_thumbnail = isset( $instance['show_thumbnail'] ) ? $instance['show_thumbnail'] : false;

            echo $args[ 'before_widget' ];       

                $cat_select = array( 
                'numberposts' => $limit,
                'cat' => $cat,  
            );

                if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts_widget' ) ) { ?>
                    <?php $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'authors', $cat_select ); 
                        if ( $related_posts ) {
                            if ( !empty( $title ) ) 
                            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>

                                <ul class="related-cat">
                                    <?php foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
                                        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <?php if ( $show_thumbnail ) : ?>
                                            <figure class="post-thumbnail">
                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('tie-large'); ?>                                               
                                            </figure>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <h3><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID);?> </a></h3>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php } //foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) ?>
                                </ul>


                        <?php } // end if ?>
                    <?php echo $args[ 'after_widget' ]; ?>          

           <?php } // end if function   ?>

    <?php } // end Widget Function
```

It's like the $after_widget doesn't work.

---

SOLVE

Thanks to @PieterGoosen! Read his code below. Wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always move my filters inside my query, this will inhibit them from showing anything when my query returns no results. You just need to move the following

```
echo $args[ 'before_widget' ];      

if ( !empty( $title ) ) 
   echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
```

to just after this line

```
if ( $related_posts ) { ?>
```

### EDIT

I have quickly rewritten one of my widgets to accommodate my related posts function. I have commented a few places where there was issues. Hope this help

```
<?php
/**
 * Related_Posts_Widget widget class
 *
 * Displays posts from a selected category
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
*/
class Related_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'widget_related_posts', 
            _x( 'Related Posts Widget', 'Related Posts Widget' ), 
            [ 'description' => __( 'Display a list of related posts.' ) ] 
        );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_related_posts';

        add_action( 'save_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) 
    {
        $cache = [];
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'widget_rel_posts', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = [];
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        $title          = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Related Posts' );
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );
        $number         = ( ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number ) {
            $number = 5;
        }
        $cat_id         = $instance['cat_id'];
        $thumbnail      = $instance['thumbnail'] ? true : false; 

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for the Related Posts Widget.
         *
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         */
        $cat_select = [ 
            'numberposts' => $number,
            'cat'         => $cat,  
        ];

        if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) { // This line was wrong, get_related_posts_widget should be get_related_posts
            $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'authors', $cat_select ); 
                if ( $related_posts ) {

                    echo $args['before_widget'];
                    if ( $title ) { // This should not be !$title
                        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
                    }               
                    ?>

                    <ul class="related-cat">
                        <?php foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
                            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php if ( $thumbnail ) : ?>
                                <figure class="post-thumbnail">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'tie-large' ); ?>                                               
                                </figure>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <h3><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID );?> </a></h3>
                            </li>
                        <?php } //foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) ?>
                    </ul>


                    <?php 
                } // end if     

            wp_reset_postdata(); // You forgot this, this is very very very important

            echo $args['after_widget']; 
        }

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_rel_posts', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {
        $instance                   = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['number']         = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['cat_id']         = (int) $new_instance['cat_id'];
        $instance['thumbnail']      = $new_instance['thumbnail'];
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['widget_related_posts']) )
            delete_option('widget_related_posts');

        return $instance;
    }

    public function flush_widget_cache() 
    {
        wp_cache_delete('widget_rel_posts', 'widget');
    }

    public function form( $instance ) 
    {

        $title      = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $number     = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $cat_id     = isset( $instance['cat_id'] ) ? absint( $instance['cat_id'] ) : 1;
        $thumbnail  = isset( $instance['thumbnail'] ) ? $instance['thumbnail'] : false; 
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cat_id'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Category Name:' )?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cat_id'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cat_id'); ?>">
                <?php 
                $this->categories = get_categories();
                foreach ( $this->categories as $cat ) {
                    $selected = ( $cat->term_id == esc_attr( $cat_id ) ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
                    $option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $cat->term_id;
                    $option = $option .'">';
                    $option = $option .$cat->name;
                    $option = $option .'</option>';
                    echo $option;
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thumbnail'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Hide post thumbnail' ); ?></label>
            <?php $checked = ( $thumbnail ) ? ' checked=\"checked\" ' : ''; ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumbnail' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumbnail' ); ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />    
        </p>

    <?php
    }

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function () 
{
    register_widget( 'Related_Posts_Widget' );
});
```

Comment: I tried but when I put the title after `if ( $related_posts ) { ?>` all the others widgets going outside the sidebar.. I don't know why.. Maybe something about the theme. Anyway I try again and I'll let you know.
Thank you

Comment: Search my profile, I have written a couple of widgets this year, check your widget against mine, maybe your problem is somewhere else. :-)

Comment: I can't get out of it.. :( When my widget has posts it looks good in the right DIV and the others widgets look good too.
But when I put the `echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];` after `if ( $related_posts ) { ?>` the others widgets are outside the sidebar.. 
Do you have some specific links where I can check? I found something but maybe you know better which of your widgets I can check against mine.. Thank you very much

Comment: Post your complete widget code

Comment: I edit the code above @PieterGoosen

Comment: So you basically want to add my related posts function in link into a widget :-)

Comment: Yes.. do you think it's crazy? :D
Anyway it works great!
I can show the posts of a selected category in the single post by current taxonomy term. ;)
The only thing is not working is the $after_widget when I would like to hide the title if the widget is empty.

Comment: No, not crazy. I will look into that. Just give me an hour or so. Just about supper time now :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Really.
If I can do something let me know.. I explain my widget better: On the back-office I can insert the widget and give a title, a limit number of posts, select a checkbox if I want to display the post thumb and a select dropdown for categories. The Taxonomy term is filter by your function. ;)

Comment: Maybe you are gonna hate me (and I'm gonna kill myself ;) ).. maybe if I also put echo `$args[ 'before_widget' ];`  after `if ( $related_posts ) {` I solve the issue.. Now I can see everything correctly also if the widget is empty! But, if you want we can check the widget together..

Comment: Hahaha, no, no problem, just logged back in. I have converted one of my widgets to include this. You had a couple of other issues which I have commented in the widget, so be sure to check it out. Also, check my update

Comment: You are fantastic! ;) I try it and I'll let you know. Thank you

Comment: It might not work out of the box straight away, but play around with it and modify as needed. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Only one question: as you know I have PHP 3.5 or something similar.. and your code gave me an error about this line:
`$cache = []`. Is correct to write it in this way: `$cache = array();` I put the code in that way and it seems to work.. But I ask you to be sure.. I promise that after holiday I will update PHP. eheh ;) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Hahahaha, no problem, yes, `$cache = array()` is correct. There are a lot of instances to change in my code.

Comment: Perfect! Yes no problem.. I will change and save your code for the future! You are too kind! thank you very much! :)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy ;-)