# Get array of current post term ID's

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm creating a little "Related posts" section on a site and I'm doing it based on terms in a custom taxonomy called "director".

How can I get an array of term ID's for the current post so that I can use them in a custom WP_Query array?

Comment: Check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188561/31545), it should answer your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the attached term IDs, use [`get_the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) and [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):

```
if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'director' ) ) {
    $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
}
```