# Related Posts Excluding Certain Categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, array

I'm using a related posts PHP WordPress query, but having trouble excluding categories. I've tried excluding via `cat` and `category__not_in` as well as both as and not as an array. What am I setting up incorrectly?

```
<?php $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories) {
    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
    $args=array(
    'cat' => array(-6,-173,-174),
    'category__in' => $category_ids,
    'category__not_in' => (6, 173, 174),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=> 3, // Number of related posts that will be displayed.
    'orderby'=>'rand' // Randomize the posts
    );
    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul class="realted-article">';
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
     </a>
     <div class="perfect-related_by-category">
        <strong><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
     <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">   
        <?php if(get_field('summary_text')=='')
            {echo substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()),0,90);}
            else{echo strip_tags(get_field('summary_text'));}?>
     </a>
     </div>
    </li>
    <? }
    echo '</ul>';
    } }
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: `cat` does not accept an array, your `category__not_in` argument is missing `array` before the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple run a `foreach` loop and exclude the terms from your returned array of terms. Just a few notes

- `cat` accepts a string or integer value, not and array
- `category__not_in` should be an array

Here is a modified version of a related posts function I recently did [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188561/31545). Please go and check it out and check out how the `$args` parameter should be used, just remember, it has moved to the third paremeter in the new function ;-)

Here is the code (*I have commented the code so you can follow it, it is untested though and requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
function get_related_posts( $taxonomy = '', $exclude = [], $args = [] )
{
    /*
     * Before we do anything and waste unnecessary time and resources, first check if we are on a single post page
     * If not, bail early and return false
     */
    if ( !is_single() )
        return false;

    /*
     * Check if we have a valid taxonomy and also if the taxonomy exists to avoid bugs further down.
     * Return false if taxonomy is invalid or does not exist
     */
    if ( !$taxonomy ) 
        return false;

    $taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
        return false;

    /*
     * We have made it to here, so we should start getting our stuff togther. 
     * Get the current post object to start of
     */
    $current_post = get_queried_object();

    /*
     * Get the post terms
     */
    $terms = get_the_terms( $current_post->ID, $taxonomy );

    /*
     * Lets only continue if we actually have post terms and if we don't have an WP_Error object. If not, return false
     */
    if ( !$terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
        return false;

    // Define our array to hold the term id'saveHTML
    $term_ids = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        // Check if we have terms to exclude and exclude them
        if ( $exclude ) {
            if ( in_array( $term->id, $exclude ) )
                continue;
        } else {
            $term_ids[] = (int) $term->term_id;
        }
    /*
     * Set the default query arguments
     */
    $defaults = [
        'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
        'post__not_in' => [$current_post->ID],
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms' => $term_ids,
                'include_children' => false
            ],
        ],
    ];

    /*
     * Validate and merge the defaults with the user passed arguments
     */
    if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    } else {
        $args = $defaults;
    }

    return $q;
}
```

You would use it as follow then

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
    $related_posts = get_related_posts( 
        'my_taxonomy_name', // Taxonomy name, if build in, in should be 'category'
        [1, 2, 3] // Array of terms to exclude
    );
    if ( $related_posts ) {
        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
            // Use your template tags and html mark up as normal like
            the_title();
            the_content();
            // etc etc
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Function makes sense. Thanks, but I'm not getting any output using the default if statements you used above.

Comment: You need to be more specific

Comment: Putting the following in the sidebar, I see nothing output:
`if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
      $related_posts = get_related_posts( 
       'my_taxonomy_name', // Taxonomy name, if build in, in should be 'category'
       [1, 2, 3] // Array of terms to exclude
      );
      if ( $related_posts ) {
       foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        // Use your template tags and html mark up as normal like
        the_title();
        the_content();
        // etc etc
       }
       wp_reset_postdata();
      }
     }`

Comment: `my_taxonomy_name` need to be the exact taxonomy name of your taxonomy, if it is the build in categories, it need to be `category`, also `[1, 2, 3]` needs to be an array of the exact category ID's you need to exclude. Please reread my answer and comments in code

Comment: Also note, code in comments are quite hard to read ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I have my excluded `category` array in there, but do not know how to determine the taxonomy name or if it's built into the categories. How do I determine one or both of those?

Comment: Also, code is comments is definitely hard to read, but you said I needed to be more specific. Didn't know how to do both.

Comment: Please read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545), it should shed some light. On the code issue, simply file an edit and add all your code in your question, then leave a small a small note in comments to the answer you are targeting about the changes, this will make it easier to read :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29203/discussion-between-keefer-and-pieter-goosen).