# how to retrieve related projects in a post but via a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a site where for each solution there are case stories, the solutions are taxonomies so it is as if the case stories were articles and the solutions categories, by viewing a solution I see the case stories linked to it. Now if I go to the page of the single case story I would like to see the related case stories, i.e. those belonging to the same solution, how can I do? if they were actually articles and categories I would do that and easily retrieve related articles

```
 <?php
  $args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'category__in' => $category_ids,
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)

  );
  $related_prod = new WP_Query($args);

  while($related_prod->have_posts()) : $related_prod->the_post();?>
```

but speaking here of a custom taxonomy how can I do there is a similar way?

Comment: Please edit this into english then request the question be reopened

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188473/) should answer your question.