# Show recent posts from a custom taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I create a custom taxonomy called "site".
I cannot figure out **what code to put in single.PHP** to show related posts ONLY from "site" custom taxonomy.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show related posts on single page by custom taxonomy on custom post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188473/show-related-posts-on-single-page-by-custom-taxonomy-on-custom-post)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add a `tax_query` to your `WP_Query` arguments, where you check that your taxonomy exists on the posts you are querying.

Here is an example that fetches the 3 latest published posts that have the taxonomy site set.

```php
$args      = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'site',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

##### Good reads

- Documentation for [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)
- Documentation for [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)